# Changing None output in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Basically I have a dictionary for books and the genre its in. I am letting the user input the book and it output the genre. I need to make it so it outputs `None` as 'Book not found'. I found a solution but I believe it's not the right way to go about targeting my problem. Could I have some guidance on how I can go and make it so `None` outputs 'Book not found'?

```
books = {
    "Life of Pi": "Adventure Fiction", 
    "The Three Musketeers": "Historical Adventure",
    "Watchmen": "Comics", 
    "Bird Box": "Horror",
    "Harry Potter":"Fantasy Fiction",
    "Good Omens": "Comedy",
    None: 'Book not found'
}

book = input()

#change this part to use the .get() method

if book in books:
    print(books.get(book))
else:
    print('Book not found')
```

Comment: Hint: `dict.get` has an optional second argument.

Comment: If your question is "why does my code never output `'Book not found'`?", then the answer is that `input()` reads a *string*, and therefore `book` *cannot possibly* be `None`, no matter what is typed.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the fine [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` takes a second argument to return if the key is not present

```
print(books.get(book, 'Book not found'))
```

Comment: That works, I had tried but I completely forgot I had been using it in an if statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
books = {
    "Life of Pi": "Adventure Fiction", 
    "The Three Musketeers": "Historical Adventure",
    "Watchmen": "Comics", 
    "Bird Box": "Horror",
    "Harry Potter":"Fantasy Fiction",
    "Good Omens": "Comedy"
}

book = input()

print(books.get(book, 'Book not found'))
```